# Validate two words using jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have an input field where user can type in any word. I want that word to be validated through jquery. Below is my js code. I am loading js validation properly.

Now I want both StringA and StringB to be validated (aka if user types in any of the words in any cases, it should validate or else will give the error message). How do I do for both words.. Below is for the first word

My js is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery.validator.addMethod("weekText", function(val) {
    var string1 = "StringA";
    if(val.toLowerCase()==string1.toLowerCase()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }, "Please enter the valid correct code word.");

$('#submitDetails').validate({
    rules: {
        entry: {
            required: true,
            weekText: true
        },
        // 2. Validation fail messages
        messages: {
            entry: {
                required: "You must enter correct code word.",
                weekText: "Please enter the valid correct code word"
            }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.validator.addMethod("weekText", function(val) {
    var strings = ["StringA","StringB"];
    flag = false
    for(i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
  if(val.toLowerCase()==strings[i].toLowerCase()){
        flag=true;
    };

    };
    if(flag){
        return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    };
    }, "Please enter the valid correct code word.");

$('#submitDetails').validate({
    rules: {
        entry: {
            required: true,
            weekText: true
        }
    },
        // 2. Validation fail messages
        messages: {
            entry: {
                required: "You must enter correct code word.",
                weekText: "Please enter the valid correct code word"
            }
       }
    });

});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/hzSvc/

Comment: @Sparky try to play with 'stringb'.Then you can find `flag` use.

Comment: No need to post same comment twice.  Yes, I see that now.

Comment: @Sparky sorry for posting two comments, I deleted one comment.